# Defining function for decimal value k[0.5+0.5]

Tags: functions, function-construction, variable-definitions, built-in-symbols, number-representation

```
k[1 + 1] = 2;
k[1 + 0.5] = 1.5;
k[0.5 + 0.5] = 1;
{k[2], k[1.5], k[1]} // TableForm

2
1.5
k[1]
```

Can you explain this phenomenon? I think the output should be

```
2
1.5
1
```

**After getting answer** : Thank you. I want to add something helpful for beginners.

```
0.5+0.5 // Head
Real

1/2+1/2 // Head
Integer
```

`1+0.5` is `1.5`

`0.5+0.5` is not `1` , but `1.`

`1/2+1/2` is `1` , not `1.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can you explain this phenomenon?

May be this will help explain it?

```
ClearAll[k]
k[0.5 + 0.5] = 1;
k[1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ClearAll[k]
k[1/2 + 1/2] = 1;
k[1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

On the other hand

```
ClearAll[k]
k[0.5 + 0.5] = 1;
k[1.0]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But now

```
ClearAll[k]
k[1/2 + 1/2] = 1;
k[1.0]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Mathematica is not like say Matlab for example. There is a big difference between `1` and `1.0` in Mathematica while in Matlab and other languages like it, these are the same.